# Docusign: adding persistent information during envelope creation

Tags: php, docusignapi

I've been on DocuSign, google, and SO and can't find a combination of search terms to tell me what I want. Working in the API, is there a way to attach a couple of pieces of information to a recipient that would then belong to that recipient and be included in API callbacks?

For instance, I'm sending out four envelopes: signer, co-signer, dealer, salesperson. I'd like to attach a field to the recipient like "our_recipient_type" equal to one of those four values. That way, when DocuSign does a callback after someone signs, I get that piece of information in the JSON so I can easily close the loop on our side.

Note, I'm not talking about text tabs, not something the signer fills out. I'm talking about a piece of background information as a property of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use text fields and have them with white font so they don't show in the document, but their values can be set/retrieved using the API.

A more advanced solution would involved custom fields (https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-custom-fields) that can have more robust rules and can also be used to manage meta-data.

There are also envelope-level custom fields (text fields) that by definition do not show in the envelope and are meta-data for the entire envelope, not a specific recipient, but they can be used for this purpose as well if you want.